# Can I dynamically place items in two-column template in Django?

Tags: django

The title might not be so clear, so let me elaborate more. I have a two-column template, and want to load some number of items in them. It would look like this:

> {{item1}}  | {{item2}}
> {{item3}}  | {{item4}}
> {{item5}}  | {{item6}}
> {{item7}}  | {{item8}}
> ...

And this is the farthest I've got in my template :

```
{% for a in answers %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="answers">{{a.title}}</div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="answers">{{a.title}}</div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Apparently, it doesn't load item as I want to. How do I make this possible? Any help is very much appreciated! :)

+Some other codes for further info: 
views.py

```
def qandaSquare(request, pk):
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(authuser=request.user.id, question_number=pk)
    
    context = {
        'answers' : answers,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/square.html', context)
```

Comment: What does it give now then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
{% for a in answers %}
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="answers">{{a.title}}</div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Refs: [divisible_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) | [forloopcounter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It almost works. The reason why I said "almost" is because when the number of items is odd, the last one is place at the middle of the template. I was hoping it to be on the left column. Any advice please?

Comment: That's because you are using `justify-content`.

Comment: Wow that perfectly works now. Thank you very much :)